# Can't install WPtoolkit in my Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nuget, wptoolkit

I am new to windows phone development and I want to use `ListPicker` in my app.

This error appears when I try to install WPtoolkit in my program.
What should I do?

### ERROR:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'WPtoolkit 4.2013.08.16'.
>   You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more
>   information, contact the package author.

Comment: Are you sure it is an WP8 app and not WP8.1? There is a huge difference between both versions

Comment: From WPToolkit Codeplex: 

You have an older version of NuGet. Install the latest NuGet from www.NuGet.org . Close and restart all the instances of Visual Studio. Now install the package. It will install correctly. WP8 projects are supported from Nuget 2.1 onwards.